# How do I get Solr to not index common words in a query?

Tags: apache, indexing, solr

I'm new working with Solr and I have an instance running properly in my server

My problem is:

When I query Solr with some terms it doesn't return results, but there are items with that term indexed. I talked with a developer who was working with this Solr instance and he remember something about a "blacklist", or "empty list", or something related, that act as a filter for queries, it's like a common words list that return poor quality results to a query, words like:
"a", "the", "for", ...

I want to know how to manage that list to remove a term from it(or add one, edit, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're talking about the stopwords filter. If you have stopword filtering active, you should see something similar to this in your field analysis within `schema.xml`

```
<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true"
                 words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
```

This references the file `stopwords.txt`, which is a standard name for this file, but a different file name may be used, so it could be different on your server. This file will contain a list of words that should be disregarded during search. You should find this file in the `conf` directory for your index (the same place as the `schema.xml` and `solrconfig.xml`). You can edit this file, though for best results, you should re-index your records after you do so.

Alternately, if you would prefer not to filter common words from your search, you can remove the reference to the `StopFilterFactory` from your field analysis entirely. Again, you should plan to reindex your records after doing so.